# Load event delayed when using video and audio tags in html5

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio, onload-event

There is an audio and video component to the webpage I'm making.  Additionally, I'm using google maps which has `google.setOnLoadCallback` which waits for the page to finish loading.  My problem is that the google map is delayed showing up until the video and audio is loaded, which is kind of too long.  Is there a way to make it so that the map will display before the video is done loading?

Comment: How are you integrating the audio and vidio? Native HTML5 elements? Flash?

Comment: I'm using `<video src="movie.mp4"/>` and `<audio src="song.mp3" />`

Answer (score 1):

Ask the browser to either not load the audio/video or to load the metadata only using the `preload` attribute:

```
<video src="movie.mp4" preload="none"></video>
```

or

```
<video src="movie.mp4" preload="metadata"></video>
```

The `audio` element will accept that parameter also.